# Javascript that removes part of string / url query parameters

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

i use the code below to format some links. Where it can add either a suffix or a prefix to the link. But i have been researching how to remove part of the link.

Example, this link below.

`https://www.torrid.com/product/boyfriend-straight-jean---vintage-stretch-medium-wash/14478822.html?cgid=Clothing_Jeans_Straight_Boyfriend#promo_id=210802_Jeans&promo_name=BoyfriendStraight_BoyfriendStraight&promo_creative=2107_FG_Denim_Boyfriend_Straight_277x702&promo_position=Jeans_Slide3&start=1`

It has superfluous data, everything after

`https://www.torrid.com/product/boyfriend-straight-jean---vintage-stretch-medium-wash/14478822.html`

Isn't needed, how can i remove everything past that point when formatting the links, before adding the suffix or prefix. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
$("#btnGenerateLinks").on("click", function() {
  var valNeed = $("#strngtime").val();

  // if (valNeed.trim().length) { // For filter blank string
  $('input[name="linktype1"]').each(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).data("link") + valNeed);
  });

  $('input[name="linktype2"]').each(function() {
    $(this).val(valNeed + $(this).data("link"));
  });
  // }
});
```

Update - Yes all query parameters

Update - Going with a simple split for now

```
var myArr = valNeed.split("?")[0];
```

Comment: Remove part of a string or specifically remove the query parameters from a URL?

Comment: Yes all query parameters to make a clean link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [URL constructor API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

```js
let url = "https://www.torrid.com/product/boyfriend-straight-jean---vintage-stretch-medium-wash/14478822.html?cgid=Clothing_Jeans_Straight_Boyfriend#promo_id=210802_Jeans&promo_name=BoyfriendStraight_BoyfriendStraight&promo_creative=2107_FG_Denim_Boyfriend_Straight_277x702&promo_position=Jeans_Slide3&start=1"
let instance = new URL(url);
let cleanURL = instance.origin + instance.pathname;
console.log(cleanURL);
// https://www.torrid.com/product/boyfriend-straight-jean---vintage-stretch-medium-wash/14478822.html
```